# Extract look-up tables from encrypted XFA PDF

Tags: xml, pdf

I am working on a web-app for some local community associations, one aspect of which is streamlining the immigration process to Canada.

The client has requested that we be able to generate these "IMM 008" forms with the PDF-417 barcodes.

https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/kits/forms/imm0008enu_2d.pdf (Adobe Reader/Acrobat required)

The main obstacle we've encountered is that the country, city, etc are not encoded as "Canada" or "Calgary" in the barcode, they have codes like "511".

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how we may extract these country codes from the XFA style PDF?

It is unfortunately encrypted so I can't just export the XML and the government has been no help so far.

Currently our top plan is to pay someone on Fiverr to manually do it which will take a long time and be prone to human error.

If anyone has a better idea, it would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download our **XFINIUM.PDF Inspector** here: https://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-inspector/xfinium-pdf-inspector-overview.html

[image: XFINIUM.PDF Inspector]

Load your file and expand the nodes as shown in the screenshot. The datasets file contains the "database" used in your form. You can copy/paste the text or save it.